# Allow instant bounty award for "exemplary answers"

Tags: feature-request, bounty

When setting a bounty on a question, I'm given several options. One of those options is "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty". I chose that option, and there's a bounty button besides every answer. When I click the answer I want to award the bounty to, it tells **me I have to wait 23 hours.**

I understand the reasoning behind forcing a wait when the bounty is set to *attract* more answers, but when one has already been chosen, then what's the point? Paraphrasing @nhinkle on the [Ask a Mod room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17527127#17527127), "*I guess the idea is that mayyyybe a WAY MUCH BETTER answer will magically come along. which in practice I doubt never ever happens.*"

So, I think for the very specific case of awarding a bounty to an existing question, the 23 hour limit should be removed.

Comment: That can be abused easily. If we do implement this, we should take care not to document it in easily seeable places to prevent abuse.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Perhaps I don't have a malicious enough mind, but how would it be abused?

Comment: People would just put that in as the reason (even though the actual reason is different) and thus sidestep the whole gist of having to wait some time.

Comment: I could see that as an easy way to move rep from one account to the other. Bounties have been (ab)used for that before, but the one-day exposure increases the chance of someone spotting the foul play.

Comment: "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty *but you could win all this extra rep if your answer is even more awesome*"

Answer (score 2):

I agree, I do not see the point in the delay when the intention is to hand out a rep quick to an answer that may have been very valuable to you At That Time, in that moment.

On the other hand, if it complicates things and adds in another layer of coding, it seems to be an easy thing to live with as it is now.

So if it would be a simple thing to implement, and would not create any great effort, then it sounds good to me. If it is some vast change and messy code implementation required to accomplish it, then it does not in any way qualify as a big deficit to the site(s).

Answer (score -1):

Bounties are meant to attract attention not just to increase ones rep.

Comment: Then what is the "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty" option for? What kind of attention is it expected to attract?